# Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync breaks images for recipient in Mac Outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are seeing an issue in Outlook for Mac (version 16.22.211.0) around "roundtripping" the mail body with `Context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` and `Context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync` when the mail body contains images. In the simplest version of this case, we are simply getting the mail body as HTML with `getAsync`, and then writing back the exact same HTML with `setAsync`.

For example:

```
function roundtripMailBody() {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, (result) => {

        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            return;
        }

        const bodyHtml = result.value;

        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(bodyHtml, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html });
    });
}
```

If the mail body contains an image (for example, from a signature, or from a user pasting an image in, or from a user inserting an image using the `Pictures` button in the ribbon), calling the function above will result in the images being broken when the mail is opened by a recipient. Interestingly, the image doesn't appear broken in the compose window immediately after writing to the body with `setAsync`; it only appears broken after sending, or when closing the compose window and reopening the mail from Drafts.

Here is some example HTML retrieved via `body.getAsync`:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-US>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal><img width=256 height=256 style='width:2.6666in;height:2.6666in'
id="Picture 2"
src="~WRS%7b81702A75-3806-F94F-ACF1-448451D74C09%7d.fld/image001.png"></p>

<p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And after writing that HTML to the body via `body.setAsync`, this is what the result of a subsequent call to `body.getAsync` returns:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-US>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal><img width=256 height=256 style='width:2.6666in;height:2.6666in'
id="Picture 2"
src="~WRS%7b81702A75-3806-F94F-ACF1-448451D74C09%7d.fld/image001.png"
style='height:2.666in;width:2.666in' alt=image001.png></p>

<p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;</p>

<p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Very little appears different from a plain HTML perspective. If the compose window is closed at this point and then reopened from the Drafts folder, `body.getAsync` returns the same thing, but the image no longer renders. If the mail is sent and then its contents inspected (in OWA for ease of access) the body is:

```
<div lang="EN-US">
<div class="x_WordSection1">
<p class="x_MsoNormal"><img data-imagetype="External" src="file:////Users/shannon/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Application%20Support/Microsoft/Temp/~WRS%7b81702A75-3806-F94F-ACF1-448451D74C09%7d.fld/image001.png" width="256" height="256" id="x_Picture_x0020_2" alt="image001.png" style="width:2.6666in; height:2.6666in"></p>
<p class="x_MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The `src` is clearly wrong on the recipient end (pointing to a local file on my machine that doesn't exist). What is the proper way to rewrite the mail body without corrupting the `src`? [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459526/office-context-mailbox-item-body-setasync-removing-original-base64-from-signatur) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415633/outlook-add-in-image-files/42559465) seem tangentially related to this problem, but we are currently **only seeing this problem when composing in Mac Outlook** (Windows Outlook 2013, Windows Outlook 2016, and Outlook Web App are all behaving as expected). We're also not seeing any reference to a `cid` in the Mac Outlook HTML blob, so even if we did want to replace the `src` with the base-64 encoding from the Rest API, we don't know how we would.

Is this behavior expected? Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, can you please log this an this issue in the [OfficeDev/office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js) repository? Members of the product team monitor that repository for issues like this, so the appropriate folks should investigate and respond after you've logged the issue there. Since the community at large won't be able to assist with product bugs/issues like this, you're not likely to benefit from posting to Stack Overflow when Office JS behavior differs between platforms.

Comment: I haven't yet, but I will. I had heard from a Microsoft team member that, in addition to monitoring issues in that repository, they also are active on Stack Overflow with questions tagged with `outlook-web-addins`, so I figured I'd give that a shot. Might as well file an issue as well!

Comment: Thanks in advance for creating the GitHub issue! In general, issues/bugs with the Office Add-ins platform or APIs should be reported directly to Microsoft by using GitHub issues in the **OfficeDev/office-js** repository. Stack Overflow is intended as a place for development-related how-to questions that could be answered by members of the development community at-large (not necessary only by Microsoft folks).

Comment: Filed at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/402!