# body.getAsync rerenders img tags in email compose

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm running into an issue where if  body.getAsync is called on an email during compose and has any img tags they get rerendered.  This is especially bad for us because we are polling for the body contents to ensure an img tag we inject does not get removed.

The experience effectively looks like the images are flashing every time body.getAsync is called.

Is this something than can be worked around or fixed?

Comment: I tried reproing this on Outlook Desktop 2016 C2R. It doesn't seem to repro. My body had an <IMG SRC = "http://someimage"> link and I called body.getAsync...nothing flickered. 

What version of Outlook are you on? Or are you on OWA? or something else? Can you send more details on the repro? (the HTML of the smallest body that repros this, and the smallest bit of api calls that you are doing that causes this?)

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue on OWA Office 365 and Mac for Outlook on Sierra.

Comment: I can repro this with just doing Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, {}, function(r) {}); in Chrome's console.

Comment: I wasn't able to repro this in chrome. I had a new e-mail with an image I had inserted via setBody, and also an image that I had inserted via the OWA UI. Then I went to the chrome console and did getBody multiple times, with no flicker. I recorded my actions here: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AsPWW0kJOnbTgYcMESbp8jlCF4YYsw 

am I doing something different? I did not attempt to repro on mac outlook yet, but is it possible that there is something specific in your code that is causing this? (maybe you are running a setbody then getbody?) Especially if this repros across 2 different clients.

Comment: I can see the issue even if I don't initiate the flow that sets the body.  Another thing I discovered, whenever the images are rerendered I see the following warning in the console "Set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url: https://outlook.office.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=AAMkAGRlN…4hJUCloTEeCQpcZaNbiZODZeoDojNQYwuLSCPj0UfEytNi1OaWGpBWtNjr28RHYSFKrPZRoIEc.. Cookie length should be less then or equal to 4096 characters."  It looks like this can sometimes happen when trying to get the cc list as well.

Comment: We do call saveAsync on load to get the id of the draft and other async calls to get the recipients.

Comment: Can you pinpoint / produce a smaller script that repros the issue. It sounds like GetBody is no longer the issue then? If we can repro it our end we can take a look.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it in Chrome anymore, but I found out that for Outlook for Mac there was a bug on our end originally thought to be unrelated.  We were adding an img tag after the close body tag, and every environment except Outlook for Mac was somehow resistant to this.

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue , I try many things , the only one that work is to call the outlook rest API and to get the attachment , then replace the img src to base 64 of the attachment.

I write the soultion [outlook add-in image & files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415633/outlook-add-in-image-files) here ...

Hope it's will helping you.