# MailItem.InternetHeaders.SetAsync() Giving Error In Outlook Web Add-In (Office JS )

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I am developing Outlook web addin using office JS.

This addin encrypts & decrypts the message.

Go through below scenario :

- The sender trying to compose the mail
- The sender adds the inline image in the mail body
- HTML of that email will be as below :

```
 <img src="https://attachment.outlook.live.net/owa/MSA%3Abhavesh- 
      mishra%40outlook.com/service.svc/s/GetAttachmentThumbnail?
      id=thumbnailType=2&isc=1&token=CANARY=&owa=outlook.live.com
      &scriptVer=20230505004.08&animation=true" 
      style="max-width:100%" 
      class="ContentPasted0 w-205 h-26" 
      originalsrc="cid:6f30b494-65bf-466a-8faf-3dd6f8b0fcbf" 
      size="211" 
      contenttype="image/png">
```

- The mail will be encrypted while sender sends the email. Above HTML of the image will also be encrypted.
- At the receiver side,When the receiver clicks on the 'decrypt' button, Whole body content is showing decrypted in the Addin task panel. But the image is showing crashed.
- When I am hitting that image URL in browser, It showing **"440 Login Timed Out"**.

To resolve this, I have added logic to convert those images to base64 string & Encrypt it. To convert those images to base64 string, I reffered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415633/outlook-add-in-image-files).

Before saving the mail (As shown in above link), I am setting internet headers by using this.

```
mail_item.internetHeaders.setAsync(internet_headers, function (set_headers_response) {});
```

I came to know that when there is inline image in the outlook mail body, The internet headers are not setting and throwing below error :

```
Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object Of Type 'object' Can't Be Converted To Type 'string'
```

When there is plain text in the body of the outlook mail, Internet headers are added successfully.

This is the flow of method which encrypts the mail and sends it :

- `mail_item.body.getAsync`
- API call which accepts content of the mail and returns encrypted content
- `mail_item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync()` to set custom properties using `set("key","value")` method
- Setting internet headers by using `mail_item.internetHeaders.setAsync({"key":"value"}, function (set_headers_response) {});`
- Converting images to base64 string by reffering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415633/outlook-add-in-image-files).
- Saving the mail and setting email body with encrypted content by using `mail_item.saveAsync()` & `mail_item.body.setAsync()` respectively.
- Mail sent

So now actually I am suffering from below two issues :

1. How to convert inline images to base64 string using JS.
2. How to set internet headers when there is inline images in the outlook mail body.

Comment: Hi @Smit Rathod, what platform and build are you on?